# Problem with separating DFT shader into two passes

Tags: image, shader, fft, pixi.js, frequency-analysis

I am working on creating a FFT shader for 2D images.

The first shader calculates the 2D DFT in one pass. The output of that shader seems to be correct.

However, when I use the second shader, which uses two passes, by first calculating the row-wise 1D DFT, and then column-wise 1D DFT, the output does not match the first.

https://repl.it/@SukantPal/Inside-PixiJS-Experiment-GPU-based-FFT-filter#script.js

I am using PixiJS filters for the shader. To run the first shader, simply remove the `applyFilter` method from `FFTFilter` & it will use the one-pass shader.

Some additional notes:

- I am using the RGB average to represent the input signal.
- Running the one-pass shader may freeze your computer/GPU for some time.

(the white padding of these images maybe from my screenshot)

Input:

[image]

Correct DFT:

[image]

Wrong DFT:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem - I was dumb enough to set `TAU` to 3.14 instead 6.28!